# Weird output files with openrtsp

Tags: rtsp, live555, openrtsp

I have stumbled across openrtsp and it's exactly what I need for capturing footage from my security cameras.

I seem to be having a weird problem when I output the video to files.  This is the command I'm using:

openRTSP -D 2 -B 10000000 -b 10000000 -4 -F alleycamnorth245 -d 86400 -P 900 -t   -u guest '' rtsp://cam_ip/user=guest_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp

The output files *seem* to have a framerate problem.  In the example above, the video comes out to the correct length (15 minutes) and there is audio for the entire 15 minutes.  However, all of the video is played super fast in the first two minutes.  All of the video is there, it's just time compressed in the first two minutes.

The camera is set to 2 frames per second, however, changing the camera setting seems to have no effect.  I've also tried a myriad of other options such as -q and -i for mov and avi output options.  Avi doesn't work, however, the mov is created with the same problem.

The cameras I'm using are from techage, however, I've tried it on one or two other cameras that are not from techage (they may have the same guts on the inside, though.  Not sure).

I feel like I've tried just about everything.  Using ffmpeg to directly pull the rtsp works as far as creating a correctly formatted video file, however, openrtsp seems to work a lot better, so, I'm hoping I can figure this out.

Thank you!!

Comment: Good luck in figuring this out. Please read up on [ask], since what seems to be lacking in this post is a question. Stack Overflow runs on questions that can receive an actual answer, so please [edit] this post to contain one.

Comment: Sorry but this is clearly not a programming question. You should ask questions that about programming and can be answered as such. I hope you find the answer to your problem anyway.